# Microsoft Edge rendering fixed div differently to other browsers

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Having a strange issue with Edge where a fixed div is displaying strange. The issue I am finding is that the div shows in a different position on edge and looks like its been moved down to the right but the buttons and clickable elements are actually still hoverable from their expected location and not from where it looks misplaced. This can also be seen in the Dev Tools which shows the buttons to be exactly where they are meant to be.

This can be seen here:
[image: This is how the div looks on edge]

This is how it is meant to display:
[image: This is how the div is meant to look]

Comment: please provide some code, so that we can debug! BTW different browser act differently because of there rendering process and JS engines.

Comment: or what you can see in devTools, if there any css property which is overroding or canceled

Comment: Could you please provide [a simple sample to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? So that we can test it in our sides. It's hard to help with only the description of the issue. You could also check if the css styles of the div are applied correctly in Edge using F12 dev tools.